# Can you name the "Full Match" group in a regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, naming

I have a regular expression with named groups, for example;

`A=(?<A>.*),B=(?<B>.*),C=(?<_C>.*)` [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/DCisxw/1)

The match groups, in this case A, B and _C are iterated to set some data on a file. However, _C is not used so the code skips this because the group name starts with an _.

There is always a "Full Match" group which has the name 0. Actually and matching group that is not named will be given a number as is the default for unnamed groups.

I was curious, is it possible to give the "Full Match" a different name, e.g _Full_Match such that the above logic still applies? Otherwise, iterating all groups includes `Group["0"]` which I don't want.

```
//c# example with System.Linq to iterate groups
foreach (var x in regex.GetGroupNames()
             .Where(y => y != "0" && y.Substring(0, 1) != "_"))
{
        /// do something with x
}
```

Comment: Can you not use `regex.GetGroupNames().Skip(1).Where(y => y.Substring(0, 1) != "_")`?

Comment: @vc74 this works as a solution but doesn't answer the question about actually giving the full match a name.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't get the option to name this group. One thing you could do is instead of using _ as a start character for groups to ignore, use the integer form and exclude any group name that cannot be parsed as an integer (including the full match one)

Comment: interesting question but have to concur with @vc74 based on my research